# Save object's last value-state

Tags: android, layout, android-dialogfragment, savestate

**INTRODUCTION**

I've got a drawing activity, where to select the color from a palette I open a `DialogFragment`.

[image]

**QUID**

First time I open the `DialogFragment`, I instatiate the bnColor object, and I give it the first button's value, so, in the color palette, the first button will appear as selected and this is the color with I would paint.

But if I then select another color in the palette, the next time I enter again to the palette, I would like this new color to appear as selected. Instead of this, always the first color appears selected.

I know this is because every time I enter the `DialogFragment`, the bnColor object is null so it gets always the first color's value. And to solve this, I would need to do something like saving the last state of the bnColor object, so when I enter the dialogFragment it will check if is the first time and it's null, or I've entered before and has a previous value saved.

But I haven't never done something like this and I don't know how to do it.

This is relevant code on dialogFragment:

```
private ImageButton bnColor;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.palette, null, false);

    if (bnColor == null) {
        LinearLayout drawLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.paint_colors);
        bnColor = (ImageButton) drawLayout.getChildAt(0);
        bnColor.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_pressed));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you serialize the `bnColor object` itself to get its last state ?

Goto [here](https://github.com/girishnair12345/Android-Tools) , you'll get a file called `CustomSharedPreference` in the source, just download and copy it to your side and save the object just as you save any other preference object

```
CustomSharedPreference mPrefs = new CustomSharedPreference(                 getApplicationContext());
OR
CustomSharedPreference mPrefs = new CustomSharedPreference( "prefsName",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, getApplicationContext());

//Save your Object
mPrefs.putObject("object", new Object());
//Retrieve it and store it
Object o = (Object)mPrefs.getObject("object", null);
```

***Note:*** The view is not serialize-able so you would have create a custom ImageButton  class like this that `implements Serializable` class, also all objects inside the `MyImageButton` should have implemented the `Serializable` interface

```
public class MyImageButton extends ImageButton implements Serializable {

    public MyImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

}
```

and use this same in your XML

```
<com.example.MyImageButton
    android:id="@+id/MyimageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I save the state this way.

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    //this is the default value, set when the dialog is created
    private String myValue = "any initial String"; 
    private TextEdit myTextEdit;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //construct the dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup myView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, null);
        builder.setView(myView);

        //find the view and set the value
        myTextEdit = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.my_text_edit);
        myTextEdit.setText(myValue);

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);

        //when the dialog is dismissed, save the users input and overwrite the initial value
        myValue = myTextEdit.getText();

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.palette, null, false);

    ImageButton  bnColor;
    if(bnColor == null)
    {
        LinearLayout drawLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.paint_colors);
        if(savedInstanceState!=null)
            bnColor= (ImageButton) getResources().getLayout(savedInstanceState.getInt("color"));
        else
        bnColor = (ImageButton) drawLayout.getChildAt(0);

        bnColor.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_pressed));
    }

    int value= bnColor.getId();

    savedInstanceState.putInt("color", value);
    onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: 1)onSaveInstanceState does nothing. Hence it woun't work. 2) savedInstanceState will be null in most cases. It woun't be null only if the dialog is re-created by a system, not when you dismiss and show it.

Comment: @Doctoror Drive could yo provide a solution in a new answer?

Comment: @masmic_87 save the color in SharedPreferences and restore it in onCreateDialog.